# Is there a way to generate a class diagram in Android Studio 3.5.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, uml, class-diagram

I want to generate a class diagram from my existing codes in my Android Studio project. Is there a way to do this?

I have seen some questions on this but they are about 5+ years old. I am looking for a more updated answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Android Studio.

However, you can use Intellij Idea Ultimate to generate the class diagram.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html